# How to sort a array/slice in a go way

Tags: go

I have the following code and ask my self is this the "go way" to solve the following requirement.

I need to print a directory tree sorted by file age.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/kr/fs"
    "os"
    "time"
    "sort"
)

type fileinfo struct {
    Path string
    age time.Duration
}

func main() {
    fmt.Print("test range of fs")

    walker := fs.Walk("../")

    var files []fileinfo

    for walker.Step() {
        if err := walker.Err(); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
            continue
        }

        age := time.Now().Sub(walker.Stat().ModTime())
        files = append(files,fileinfo{walker.Path(),age})
    }

    sort.Slice(files, func(i, j int) bool {
        return files[i].age < files[j].age
    })
    for i:=0; i < len(files) ; i++ {
        fmt.Print("File path: ",files[i].Path," age: ",files[i].age,"\n")
    }
}
```

What's your opinion to the code?

Thanks for help

Comment: Why are you using a 3rd party lib (`github.com/kr/fs`) for this? What's wrong  with the standard lib's [`filepath.Walk()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk)? Using that would be the "go way".

Comment: Because I just wanted to use a small code. Now it looks like it's better to use the std lib for this.

Comment: Belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i:=0; i < len(files) ; i++ {
    fmt.Print("File path: ",files[i].Path," age: ",files[i].age,"\n")
}
```

`for` loops over arrays are better written using `range` iterator. This makes the code easier to read, avoids silly mistakes, and it works with other structures like maps and channels.

```
for _,file := range files {
    fmt.Print("File path: ",file.Path," age: ",file.age,"\n")
}
```

See [Go by Example: Range](https://gobyexample.com/range) for more.

---

Since you have a newline at the end and a space between each element, `fmt.Println` might work out better than `fmt.Print`. It automatically puts spaces between each element and a newline at the end.

```
fmt.Println("File path:", file.Path, "age:", file.age)
```

Comment: Ranging over a slice of structs is often less efficient than using indices, as the former needs to copy all the elements of the slice one-by-one.. Range still can be used, but it's faster if used only for indices in case of slice of structs.

Comment: @icza You're technically correct, but that's the wrong way to think in Go. In Go, the decision to pass by value or pass by pointer (or in this case, thing which can be modified) should depend on whether you intend to alter the original or not. The consideration is safety, not tweaking performance. And `range` is quite performant, it reuses the same memory for the iterator (something which can catch people out). Use `range` and then only switch to a traditional `for` loop if profiling says its necessary for performance.